# how rigorous or legible must prior art be?

Tags: prior-art, prior-art-request, patent-applications

As I understand it, prior can come from any source and not just prior patents.

So for example, a YouTube video can be prior art, correct?

If so, what is the standard for a source to become sufficient prior art?

In a typical YouTube video, lax everyday language is used.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a lawyer. That said, prior art can come from any source. During prosecution of the application, most likely sources are ones that the examiner can find. If someone challenges your patent then pretty much any public source. It doesn't matter how formal the language is, just whether it anticipates the patents claims.

Answer (score 1):

The standard phrase is “it’s good for what it teaches”. For anticipating prior art it needs to contain all limitations of a particular claim in a single embodiment. For obviousness prior art the issues are much more complicated because multiple references are combined to achieve the claimed invention.